# jQuery validate rule ONLY AT SUBMIT

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Say i have a form that looks up city, state locations.  if the user enters an incorrect city, state, i want the form to be able to check the database against the users input, and see if the input is valid or not.  If it is not, i want the user to be prompt.

So form Validate is the plugin for me.

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
       citystate: {
           required: true,
           myCustomAjaxSyncronousCheckAgainstDBRule: true
       }

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        if ($("#form").valid()) {
            form.submit();
        }
    }
});
```

Now say this form has to be used in 4 different places in my website, so it would suck to refactor out the myCustomAjaxSyncronousCheckAgainsDBRule (Fake name btw) and have the same code 4 times throughout my website.  So that is why i created a custom rule in the JS file.  But is there a way that the rule CAN ONLY be checked at Submit time.  Since if there is an invalid user input, it will check it at EVERY key stroke, which can be quite cumbersome.  Especially since i have jQuery.ui.autocomplete running inconjuction.

Comment: check my answer below for an alternative

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As an alternative an a more straightforward way you can pass a function to the `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` settings of the jquery.validator to decide if an element has to be validated in those events or not, as this :

```
jQuery.validator.defaults.onfocusout = function (element, event) {
    // detectect if is the element you dont want validate
    // the element has to have the attribute 'data-control="mycitycontrol"'
    // you can also identify your element as you please
    if ($(element).data("control") === "mycitycontrol") return;
    if (!this.checkable(element) && (element.name in this.submitted || !this.optional(element))) {
        this.element(element);
    }
}
jQuery.validator.defaults.onkeyup = function (element, event) {
    // detectect if is the element you dont want validate
    // the element has to have the attribute 'data-control="mycitycontrol"'
    // you can also identify your element as you please
    if ($(element).data("control") === "mycitycontrol") return;
    if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "") {
        return;
    } 
    else if (element.name in this.submitted || element === this.lastElement) {
        this.element(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: If this still was my problem, this is how i would solve this.

Comment: An alternative way to accomplish this: $("#myfield").on("focusout keyup", function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });

Comment: This answer deserves more votes, way better than the rest

Comment: You can set that individually for a form: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045731/f-settingsg-call-is-not-a-function-with-anything-but-submit-validation

Answer (score 36):

All of the validations can be set independently (onclick, onkeypress,onsubmit,etc.)

Demos and details are available on the docs site
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate

```
$("#form").validate({
   onkeyup: false,
   onclick: false
})
```

Comment: what if we want only 1 rule to have non onkeyup validation.  Or onclick.  but the rest are ok.  By this, i mean one of the many inputs to have only on submit checking.

Comment: You mean within a single form have a single field not follow the validate settings? Not sure that you can do that without running a prototype to validate(). In that case I'd use the metadata plugin and have it not bind to those fields (though this may involve breaking the delegate).

Comment: All hidden fields are only validated before the form is submitted because they never receive focus. Perhaps you can update the value of a hidden input and apply the rule to that.

Comment: @iivel you can choose which elements don't follow the settings, actually you can modify the settings in order to achive that. Check my answer below

Comment: @Michael those validation parameters can be set to functions that return a boolean. This boolean will tell the validation plugin to validate the input or not.
For example: if you want to validate only the `<input id="email"` onkeyup, you can do something like that:
`onkeyup:function(element){ return (element.id === 'email'); }`
This function will return `true` only if the element's ID is `email`, so this is the only input that will be validated onkeyup.
See the documentation for onkeyup event: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#onkeyup

Answer (score 9):

```
$.extend($("#form-id").validate().settings, { 
    onkeyup: false, 
    onfocusout: false 
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's an idea that might work: separately bind the keyup function for your field that you don't want the keyup event to be validated on, and have it not bubble:

```
$('#citystateID').bind('keyup',function(){
   return false; 
});
```

I couldn't figure out how to bind the validator specific events (focusin and focusout), so it would still run validations whenever focus left your "citystate" input, but it's closer to what you wanted?

I briefly tested this here: http://jsfiddle.net/svUdp/  seemed to work alright (watch your console to see what happens - lots of events being triggered, but not so many validates).

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to get a particular validation method to fire ONLY on the submit event while allowing other validation methods to fire normally (e.g., on the onkeyup event), then you can dynamically add the rule when the submit event fires, then remove it after the validation is performed. The ordering of the bindings is important; keep them in order.

```
$('#form').bind('submit', function(event) {
    $('#citystate').rules('add', {myCustomAjaxSyncronousCheckAgainstDBRule: true});
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        citystate: { required: true }
    }
});

$('#form').bind('submit', function(event) {
    $('#citystate').rules('remove', 'myCustomAjaxSyncronousCheckAgainstDBRule');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

`$("#form").validate({
   onfocusout: false,
   onkeyup: false,
   onclick: false
});`

Comment: Unfortunately, @iivel has already given an identical answer. so i cannot accept this.