# f.settings[g].call is not a function with anything but submit validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to get the jquery validation plugin working with onkeyup, or onfocusout options.  Each time I add these options and trigger one of them I get an error. The validation works if I submit my form.

I am not really allowed to post the form I am working on, however I have created similar issues with a very simple form that I was just loading up in a directory with all the js under the subdirectories static/js/.

I am using jquery 1.6.2 and jquery validation 1.9.0

Anyone have any thoughts?

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var validator = $('#submitform').validate({
        rules: {
            name: 'required',
            phone: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 12
            },
            team: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 1
            },
            fax: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 12
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: 'Your name is required',
            phone: 'Your phone number is required',
            team: 'Your extension number is required',
            fax: 'Your fax number is required'
        },
        // the errorPlacement has to take the table layout into account 
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
            if ( element.is(":radio") ) 
                error.appendTo( element.parent().next().next() ); 
            else if ( element.is(":checkbox") ) 
                error.appendTo ( element.next() ); 
            else 
                error.appendTo( element.parent() ); 
        }, 
        onfocusout: true,
        // specifying a submitHandler prevents the default submit, good for the demo 
        submitHandler: function() { 
            alert("submitted!"); 
        }, 
        // set this class to error-labels to indicate valid fields 
        success: function(label) { 
            // set   as text for IE 
            label.html(" ").addClass("checked"); 
        } 
    });
});
</script>

<form id="submitform" action=".">

<label for="name">Your Name:</label>
<input id="ins_name" type="text" name="name"  maxlength="40" />

<label for="phone">Phone:</label>
<input name="phone" maxlength="14" type="text" id="phone" />

<label for="extension">Extension:</label>
<input name="extension" maxlength="10" type="text" id="extension" />

<label for="fax">Fax:</label>
<input name="fax" maxlength="14" type="text" id="fax" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit">   
</form>
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that onfocusout should be a function.

Comment: According to the docs it is just an option  - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Comment: options are properties of the configuration object, their values can anything.  In this case, I'm guessing that the type should be function because it's for an event handler (it's common in jQuery) and it just wasn't documented well (like most plugins).

Comment: AutoSponge - You are correct, you want to answer the question with an answer?

Comment: Yes, make onfocusout a function instead Of the Boolean true.

Answer (score 26):

As stated above, the documentation is flawed. You actually need to set the `onfocusout` option to a function that accepts the element being validated as a parameter. Here is a working code sample :

```
$("#form").validate({
    onfocusout: function(element) {$(element).valid()}
});
```

Comment: For me, only the required fields were not validated on focus out, my digit validators were working on focus out. This fixed it!

Answer (score 4):

in my case there was a line `onkeyup: true` then i changed it to `false`

```
onkeyup: false
```

but i still don't know when the error started coming. :)