# How to avoid jQuery validator firing on textbox tab out

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have following jQuery validator in a MVC4  scenario. It is working fine. But I need the validation only when the user clicks the button; not when user change the textbox focus. How do we make this change?

**jQuery**

```
$(function ()
{

jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add
    ("lijovalidator", ["param"], function (options)
    {
        options.rules["lijovalidator"] = options.params.param;
        options.messages["lijovalidator"] = options.message;
    });

jQuery.validator.addMethod("lijovalidator",
function (value, element, param) {

    alert(value);
    alert(param);
    alert(element);
    alert($("#" + param).val());

    return false;


});

}(jQuery));
```

**Client Validation in SelctedValueCheckAttribute**

```
public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {

            ModelClientValidationRule mcvr = new ModelClientValidationRule();
            mcvr.ValidationType = "enteredvaluescheck";
            mcvr.ErrorMessage = "Selected Value must be in given range";
            mcvr.ValidationParameters.Add("param", OtherProperty);
            mcvr.ValidationType = "lijovalidator";
            yield return mcvr;
        }
```

**Model**

```
   public class CrossFieldValidation
    {

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }

        [SelctedValueCheckAttribute("TxtCrossField") ]
        public string SelectedValue { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Quantity:")]
        public string TxtCrossField{ get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ShippingItems { get; set; }

        [SelctedValueCheckAttribute("ShippingValue")]
        public string SelectedShippingItemValue { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Quantity:")]
        [Required]
        public string ShippingValue { get; set; }



    }
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252373/jquery-validate-rule-only-at-submit) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use as below:

```
$(function(){
   $(window).blur(function(){
      return true;
   });
});
```

Comment: many thanks .. where i need to put this i placed custom function javascript in js file ... do u want me to put in js file..

Comment: You can put in Js file as well as in razor file as per your comfort level.

Comment: ElementId is your textboxId

Comment: thanq but I have got three text boxes and starting it self i dont want the tab change validation ....

Comment: i have got three textboxes that I need to avoid the tab validation and i need to get the validation function works on only submit button itself

Comment: sorry, its not working when i tried that function in inside js file and in the view itself ...