# Jquery validation for form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have use the jquery.validate.js for validate the input  field present in the form .

In this  I have use the following

Validationrule, required, minlength 3 for input field.

In my case once start the editing in input , error message displayed,

My requirement is I want to show the error message only button click/EnterKey .

Is it possible to achieve this using jquery.validate.js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252373/jquery-validate-rule-only-at-submit

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation you need to disable onfocusout: and onkeyup: options

refer [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) for more help